# Docker for windows: docker pull elasticsearch read: connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-for-windows, docker-pull

I am using docker for windows (windows 10) with Linux containers.
I am unable to pull out elastic search image. I am trying below:

```
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.1.0
```

It is continuously giving me following error:

```
7.1.0: Pulling from elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss
8ba884070f61: Already exists
90c8f93ef11f: Pull complete
2b50c7b87a00: Pull complete
e24c84b95da5: Downloading [==================================================>]  229.7MB/229.7MB
83fffb4337ad: Download complete
f7be32dbf95a: Download complete
239f829e6b55: Download complete
read tcp 192.168.65.3:56490->13.249.166.200:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

However, I am able to pull Kibana image successfully.

I searched for various links on net, but could not find info which solves the problem. I don't have any proxy setup on my machine.

Please help.

EDIT 1:
I also tried below, but did not work

```
docker pull elasticsearch:7.1.1
7.1.1: Pulling from library/elasticsearch
8ba884070f61: Already exists
bc017bf6a4d5: Pull complete
66463b85d389: Pull complete
837fa1486a34: Downloading [==================================================>]  207.2MB/207.2MB
4e79d4f9236b: Download complete
fca20e6168be: Download complete
d286e388da12: Download complete
read tcp 192.168.65.3:44896->104.18.122.25:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

Comment: do you use boot2docker?

Comment: No. I use docker for windows.

Comment: Also not work on my side to download layer e24c84b95da5, I guess you can try it again later.

Comment: I am trying it since one day but no luck.

Comment: I tried for older elastic versions also, but these failed also.

Comment: I also use Docker for Windows on Windows 10. Trying to pull your image myself. So far everything is fine; waiting for the pull to finish. Days back, I pulled the `elasticsearch` and `logstash` images from the same repository (`docker.elastic.co`) without any error. From your error message, it rather seems to be a transient network failure; shouldn't last very long.

Comment: Have successfully pulled image right now. 
`docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.1.0`
`7.1.0: Pulling from elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss`
`8ba884070f61: Already exists`
`90c8f93ef11f: Pull complete`
`2b50c7b87a00: Pull complete`
`e24c84b95da5: Pull complete`
`83fffb4337ad: Pull complete`
`f7be32dbf95a: Pull complete`
`239f829e6b55: Pull complete`
`Digest: sha256:0d52ed7654150c8ef2a539910d4b72295c1b9137b286241b79d0deac44e9bedf`
`Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.1.0`.

Comment: I am still facing error, any config issue on my setup?? Surprisingly, I am able to fetch filebeat image just now. Also, i notices every time, below particular images are retried couple of times and then they are downloaded fully (as per size shown) but still get the issue.90c8f93ef11f: Downloading [=>                                                 ]  37.03MB/37.03MB
2b50c7b87a00: Download complete
e24c84b95da5: Downloading [>                                                  ]  263.3MB/263.3MB

Comment: can I try pulling elastic image from any other repository?

Comment: Can i get base elastic search image file from somewhere so that i can build it on my own?

Comment: 1. Hard to be precise, however, I still think it's a transient error.
2. You'd better try building the image from the Elasticsearch official [Docker file](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/7.0/distribution/docker/src/docker). It builds an Elasticsearch image from a _CentOS_ base image; no need for any Elasticsearch base image.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with this image build.